# jQuery infinite loop animation problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm trying to do a simple loop on a jQuery animation but it won't work, where I'm wrong?

```
var time = 750;
var go_up = true;

$('#vittorio a').hover(function () {
    checkMovement ();
}, function () {
    $('#heart').stop().animate({
        top:'0px'
    }, 1500);
});

function moveHeart (pos) {
    $('#heart').stop().animate({
        top:pos
    }, time, function () {
        checkMovement();
    });
}

function checkMovement () {
    if (!go_up) {
        go_up = true;
        pos = '3px';
    } else {
        go_up = false;
        pos = '-3px';
    }

     moveHeart (pos);
}
```

The loop works only once.

Comment: '-3px' should be '-=3px' ?a and '3px' should be '+=3px' ?

Comment: it should just fluctuate +3px to -3px and vice versa in loop, but the function is called only once.

Comment: you forgot to use semicolon on checkMovement() call

Answer (score 0):

seems you forgot to use semicolon on checkMovement() call

Comment: I think the problem is `checkMovement();` is not accessible from the `callback` function in `jQuery` animation